# Cannot find 'SwiftUIWebView' in scope

Tags: xcode6

I'm completing my Webview application, but I run into the following error:

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

```
var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G01gd.jpg)
SwiftUIWebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/"))

```
            .navigationTitle("WebView")

    }

}
```

}

struct ContenView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

```
static var previews: some View {

    ContentView()

}
```

}

Comment: Don't copy and paste code from other sources and try to pass it as your own `SwiftUIWebView` is a custom SwiftUI `View` you need it as part of your code to be able to find it.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Go back to the tutorial, question, git, etc. that the code came from and find it. Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) Don’t start by just copy and pasting someone else’s code, learn the basics.

Comment: Thank you Lorem ipsum. You're absolutely right, I'll study more about it. Thank you for your attention and empathy.